# How to find what 2 sounds have in common?

Tags: audio, video, encoding, ffmpeg

Thank you for your time.

I have a video, with 2 audios tracks (same lenght) (audio1 : en, audio2: jap).

I try to figure how to export an audio where theses track are identical (blank sound otherwise) or better, the times periods where these have sound in commmon

I think ffmpeg is a good start and i use it occasionally, but this one is a bit too hard for me.

Any ideas ?

Many thanks,
Sorry for my aproximate english.

Thomaz

->EDIT
Got it with scypi.

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read, write
en = read("000001_output_en.wav")
jap = read("000001_output_jp.wav")
out=(en[1]*en[1]==jap[1])
write("output_processed.wav",en[0],out)
```

to find their common silences :

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read, write
en = read("000001_output_en.wav")
jap = read("000001_output_jp.wav")
out=(en[1]*jap[1])
write("output_processed.wav",en[0],out)
```

Comment: you should move your solution out of above and post it as the answer to this question ... makes it easier for folks to realize this question has a solution ... just say'en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it with scypi.

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read, write
en = read("000001_output_en.wav")
jap = read("000001_output_jp.wav")
out=(en[1]*en[1]==jap[1])
write("output_processed.wav",en[0],out)
```

to find their common silences :

```
from scipy.io.wavfile import read, write
en = read("000001_output_en.wav")
jap = read("000001_output_jp.wav")
out=(en[1]*jap[1])
write("output_processed.wav",en[0],out)
```